# Access Denied for User ODBC @ localhost

Tags: windows, cmd, mysql-workbench, mysql

i have installed Mysql on Windows7, i used mysql with mysql command line client & i also use Mysqldump in windows cmd, & it was working without any problem. But today, i tried to export database using mysqldump with this command in cmd

```
mysqldump –u root -p mypassword db_name > f:\mydb.sql
```

i tried many other commands and i always see error

```
Access Denied for User 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: yes) when trying to connect
```

as you can see, in mysqldump command i am using root as user then why i get user ODBC error ? one more thing, using mysql command line client i am still using mysql normally without any problem using root as user. i also tried to login in cmd with this command

```
mysql –u root -p mypassword
```

but still same error. and my password is 100% correct. kindly tell me how to solve this problem.  Thanks

Comment: While not completely what you are looking for, this may help - http://www.kixtart.org/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=158186

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried storing pass in the cfg file? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html

Comment: then go on and let us know

Answer (score 0):

try from command line:

> ```
> mysql -u root -p
> ```
>
> and then, when you are being asked for password, just type it.
>     Try the same with mysqldump command without typing your password after -p.